# Automapper maping navigation property on a one to one relationship

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map a navigation property on a one to one relationship but I'm getting null values, here are my entities

```
   public class Client
   {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public Branch Branch{ get; set; }
   }
```

```
   public class Branch
   {
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

And this is my Dto

```
   public class ClientDto
   {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
   }
```

And these are the mapping configurations I have tried

```
   public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>().
                ForMember(
                dest => dest.BranchName, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom (src => src.Branch.Name)
                );
        }
    }
```

and

```
           CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>().IncludeMembers(src => src.Branch);
           CreateMap<Branch, ClientDto>().ForMember(
              dest => dest.BranchName, 
              opt => opt.MapFrom(b => b.Name)
            );
```

in both cases I got nulls on BranchName, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. The example should clearly show that the original `Client` object has the `Branch` property set with a name and that after calling `Map` you don't have any `BranchName` set.

Comment: Please make sure your actual object (usually from database using ef) includes the desired navigation property by using the `Include`

Comment: Thank you very much JAHANGIR, that solved the problem, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @S.M.JAHANGIR I'm having the same exact issue. Could you please throw more light on your recommendation?

Comment: @cmoe see my answer bellow.

Comment: That was what I was missing in my repository. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your actual object (usually from database using ef) includes the desired navigation property by using the Include – S. M. JAHANGIR

This is the correct answer.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I have the same issue but the answer is not really clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `Include` the navigation property on your repository (if using) implementation:

```
var client = await _context.Clients.Include(c => c.Branch).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
```